# How to match a regex with ng-model in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to check for a certain pattern (regex) on the value which is entered in a textbox. For example, the regex for PAN no. is `/^[A-Z]{5}\d{4}[A-Z]{1}$/`

Now when a user enters their PAN no in the textbox, I want to check whether it is according to the pattern. If not, then I will show a validation error.

I am not sure where to begin with, I've already tried validation libraries but couldn't get them to do this. Any suggestions will be helpful.

`PAN No. is a number issued by the Income Tax Authority of India`

Note: `I want to do it only in AngularJS`

Comment: You can create a similar function and add it to scope and then bind it to directive

Comment: I mentioned I want to do it in AngularJS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AngularJS has a special validation check for *regex* values - `ng-pattern`

This should do it:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="PAN" ng-pattern="/^[A-Z]{5}\d{4}[A-Z]{1}$/" required>
<span ng-show="PAN.$error.pattern">Invalid PAN</span>
```

Comment: Absolutely! Totally forgot about `ng-pattern`

Thanks a lot!